# Visual studio code not detecting virtual device emulator

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, adb, mobile-development

I want to get into mobile app development using flutter and writing my code on visual studio code but vscode won't detect my android studio virtual device. If you can help how do i fix this? Here is a screenshot of how it is currently [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka6L5.png)

Comment: First let it complete analyzing which is at the bottom left in the screenshot you have posted. Then close the running emulator instance and click on No Device on the bottom right, you will see a list of emulator(s) you have created. Select any one and wait for it to complete load, once it loads, you will see the emulator name in place of No devices.

Comment: @gegobyte does the analyzing require an internet connection? because it usually analyzes forever and i end up closing vscode and then opening it again. Is it normal to use an android studio emulator? because what i did was open android studio, then open an adb there, then close android studio without closing the adb. Is that normal or am i doing it all wrong?

Comment: There is a lot of people that launch the emulator from android studio because they don’t know the command. It works perfectly so that would not be the problem.